# How to solve Laravel union queries with different number of columns

Tags: laravel

I have two tables `contact_us` and `upload_new_car.`

`contact_us` table contains columns:

```
id
name
email
phone
message
created_at
updated_at
```

`upload_new_car` contains columns:

```
id 
name     
phone_number     
car_name     
car_price    
location 
car_model_year   
car_model    
variant  
driven   
fuel 
transmission     
city     
no_of_owners     
upload_1     
upload_2     
upload_3     
upload_4     
upload_5     
created_at   
updated_at
```

How can I get the UNION of these tables in Laravel? Please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not allowing to different size of columns is not laravel's businuess. It is a matter of SQL .You can follow [[this link](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_union.asp)] for more info about UNION statements .

On the other hand for laravel you can use those syntax using union (We can benefit from selecting the same count of columns from each tables).

```
$first = DB::table('contact_us')
            ->select('name','phone');

$users = DB::table('users')
            ->select('name','phone_number as phone')
            ->union($first)
            ->get();
dd($users)
```